# How to delete files and folders in my documents folder without use of FSO command?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete all files and folders in the My Documents folder. I tried FSO create object command to delete files but not folders in the My Documents folder. Is there any other way to delete files and folders in the My Document folder?

This is my code.

```
Sub GetSpecialFolderPath()

Dim objSFolders As Object

Dim MyPath As String

Set objSFolders = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders

MyPath = objSFolders("mydocuments")

Dim FSO As Object

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    MyPath = .Range("B2").Value

    If Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then

        MyPath = Left(MyPath, Len(MyPath) - 1)

    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(MyPath) = False Then

        MsgBox MyPath & " doesn't exist"

        Exit Sub

    End If

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you propose doesn't work. 
You need to have two distinct variables for the path you get with 
"MyPath = objSFolders("mydocuments")"
and the path you get with 
"MyPath = .Range("B2").Value"

Example:
use MyDocumentsPath for the first path and MyTestPath for the second path and then write 
"If FSO.FolderExists(MyDocumentsPath & "\" & MyTestPath ) = False Then"
for the test of the directory